# Pig load array to mongo

Tags: mongodb, apache-pig

I would like to transform my output array:

I have the following code:

```
x = LOAD '$INPU'
            USING PigStorage('\\u001')
            AS (
                  product_id:chararray,
                  size:chararray
                 );

grouped = GROUP x BY (product_id);

 sizes = FOREACH grouped {
                       sizes = DISTINCT $1.size;
                       GENERATE
                         $0 AS product_id,
                         sizes AS sizes;
                     }

 output = foreach sizes generate
    product_id as id,
    sizes as sizes;

STORE output
INTO '$output'
USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoInsertStorage('id');
```

this result the following:

```
"product_id" :"123",
"sizes": [ 
{
"size": "X"
},
{
"size": "M"
},
{
"size": "L"
}
]
```

It is possible to change the output to the following? :

```
product_id: "123",
sizes": ["X", "M", "L"]
```

i have tried flatten and BagToTuple but could not find a solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already seen it, but [this page on mongodb.hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/pig/README.md) explains in great detail, and with examples, how to use *MongoInsertStorage* (and also *MongoUpdateStorage*).

I have to admit, I didn't see an option there to do what you'd like; indeed, in their example they get a similar result to yours.

However, on thing that might work is to use *MongoUpdateStorage* to do upserts. I'm not sure it will work, but if you use a general query with no parameters on a new or empty collection, it can do the job. If you look at the bottom part of the link I provided, they explain how to get output that looks like this

> { "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "gender":"male", "age" : 19, "cars" : ["a", "b", "c"], "first" : "Daniel", "last" : "Alabi" }

instead of this

> { "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "gender":"male", "age" : 19, "cars" : [{"car": "a"}, {"car":"b"}, {"car":"c"}], "first" : "Daniel", "last" : "Alabi" }

(I'm referring to the change in the *cars* field).

One last question - in your example, you change the name of *product_id* to *id* in your last *foreach* ... but in the output you showed, it still has the name *product_id*. Could it be you've been sending the wrong relation to *MongoInsertStorage?*

And, finally, another option is to save your collection as BSON and then use *mongorestore* on it - this option is also explained on that page.

Comment: I using mongo update just to simplify the problem i used insert in the above example.

Comment: and is there any way to create a list of strings simply? like sizes: X,M,L ?

Comment: Can you include the update command you used in your question?

Comment: The link is broken. Could you share a valid reference?